# Rails 4: count unread messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a simple messaging system. 
How do I display the number of total unread messages to every user in all conversations they are participating in? 
Also, when the user goes to '/conversations' how do I recognize and label every conversation that has messages not read by the current_user?

So far I have this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation, :counter_cache => true
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  has_many :messages

  belongs_to :recipient,
   :class_name => 'User',
   :primary_key => 'user_id',
   :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :messages, :through => :conversations 
end
```

schema

```
  create_table "conversations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.integer  "messages_count", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "conversation_id"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: How can you tell if a message is unread?

Comment: I could add 'read_at' column, but I don't know how to make it work and record a time a specific message has been read by the recipient. All messages are in a conversation, so there is not a 'show' action for a specific message.

Comment: yes, the answer to the issue is exactly in the question by @infused.

Comment: Did any of you build a messaging system before and how did you do it? Are there any tutorials that cover the subject?

Comment: One simple solution is to go with your `read_at` column. You can make it so that when the user clicks the conversation to read it, the system marks all messages in that conversation as "read". So for example, you can iterate through the message objects and add `Time.now` to the `read_at` column if it is currently empty.

Comment: @Ege Erzos Which user? Who will trigger the update of 'read_at' column?